SPARQL values retrieving only 1 sample
I've got several instances of entities of several types in my kg.  I'd like to use VALUES to describe all my types and use those values to select 1 (sample) instance and then select all values of that subject.  Something like
select * where {

  select ?s where {   
    ?typ VALUES ( ex:t1 ex:t2 ex:t3 ) .
    ?s a ?typ .
    # get one ?s of type ex:t1, ex:t2, ex:t3
  } limit 1
  ?s ?p ?o .
}

above will only grab 1 value before exiting.  I've tried putting VALUES outside the subquery and it doesn't work either.  Anyway to do what I want?

you're lucky - right now in SPARQL 1.1  it only works for 1 sample by using the aggregate function sample as shown below by @Ivo-Velitchkov . What you technically are asking for is a feature in SQL world dubbed "correlated query" - this is not part of SPARQL 1.1 but will be a feature of SPARQL 1.2 standard. This will then make it easier to iterate a given left-hand side to run the right-hand side, e.g. then solving tasks like  "give me the 5 largest cities per country"

You need to fix the syntax of VALUES and then actually ask for samples.
SELECT ?typ (SAMPLE (?s) AS ?sample_s)
WHERE {
  VALUES ?typ {ex:t1 ex:t2 ex:t3}
  ?s a ?typ .
}
GROUP BY ?typ
LIMIT 3

I added GROUP BY for clarity. You can omit it.
If you want a single result with three samples, you get that using subqueries.
SELECT ?s1 ?s2 ?s3
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?s1 WHERE {
      ?s1 a ex:t1 .
    } LIMIT 1
  }
  {
    SELECT ?s2 WHERE {
      ?s2 a ex:t2 .
    } LIMIT 1
  }
  {
    SELECT ?s3 WHERE {
      ?s3 a ex:t3 .
    } LIMIT 1
  }
}
LIMIT 1

Update based on your comment

Hi, I indeed want your second example but have 30 values to use

Not much more can be done with SPARQL 1.1 but asking for samples separately is perhaps shorter than 30 subqueries:
SELECT 
  (SAMPLE(?st1) AS ?t1_sample)
  (SAMPLE(?st2) AS ?t2_sample)
  (SAMPLE(?st3) AS ?t3_sample)
WHERE {
  { ?st1 a ex:t1 }
  { ?st2 a ex:t2 }
  { ?st3 a ex:t3 }
}
LIMIT 1


Hi, I indeed want your second example but have 30 values to use. Do I need to do it long hand?

Can you please elaborate on what are the limitations of the first suggestion for what you are trying to achieve?

hi, you samples query works.  only downside is that it appears to retrieve all matches before sampling, which makes sense, but is slow on large KGs. Thanks !
